Seven-Ten Card Game
Looking for rules to a card game we knew as “Seven-Ten” back in the 70’s. It’s not Sevens, Pitch, Nickels or Phase 10. We used nickels to buy discards and the winner(s) won the pot. I think the overall winner had the lowest score, but it could be split if a player finished with an exact count of 710.
I’ve included a photo of the score sheet. You play 7 hands, collecting sets - 2 sets of 3, 1 set of 4, etc. There are wildcards, I think starting with jokers, then the last three hands adds additional wildcards.
Can’t remember specific rules - number of cards dealt, how to “buy” discards, scoring, etc. Any help is greatly appreciated. 

Maybe it'll help get the ball rolling, but this is almost certainly a type of Contract Rummy.
Two things that might help dig up more precise rules:

What part of the world is this from?
Do you have a completed score sheet?

I'll attempt a reconstruction, my best guess is that seven cards are dealt in the hands above the double line and ten cards are dealt in the hands after the double line. This would explain the name seven-ten and the easyness of the second and fourth contract (one 4 and one 5, respectively). These contracts would be too easy if the hand size increased by one card every round.

The Contract Rummy Pagat page contains the common rules for games of this family.
Here's the mechanism for an ordinary turn according to Pagat.

Draw the top card of the discard pile or the top card of the stock.
Meld or lay off*
Discard.

For number 2, your initial meld must satisfy the contract for the round exactly, it cannot contain additional cards. Also, you may only lay off if you have completed your initial meld on a previous term. Pagat says You may not lay off before or on the same turn in which you meld, which strictly speaking is ambiguous and might mean that laying off is illegal on a turn in which you meld, but that is very unlike most Rummy games. I think a more reasonable interpretation is that on the turn in which you satisfy your initial meld requirement, you must do precisely that and cannot make extra melds or lay off additional cards.
The basic mechanism in the Pagat page for taking a discard out of turn is just that you ask May I? and then you get the discard, plus a penalty from the top of the stock.
This mechanism seems to vary from game to game in the family.
Here's a quote from the Caribbean Kalooki Pagat Page.

Calling
If you have not yet laid down any cards, and you want to take a card discarded by another player when it is not your turn to play next, you can call the card. The player whose turn it is to play has two options:

Allow the call. The player whose turn it is gives the top discard to the player who called it. The calling player takes the discard and must also draw one extra card from the stock, but cannot lay down any cards or discard at this time. The caller will from now on have two extra cards in their hand. The play then reverts to the player whose turn was interrupted by the call, who must draw from the stock, and continue the turn in the usual way.

Refuse the call. If the player whose turn it is has not yet laid down, they have the right to take the discard for themselves, rather than giving it to the caller and drawing from the stock; the call then has no effect.


Calling is subject to the following rules.

If several people try to call the same card, the person who calls first gets the card, assuming that the person whose turn it is allows the call. No one can call a card before it reaches the table.
There can only be one call per turn: the card underneath the called card cannot be called - anyone who wanted it should have called it when it was first discarded.
Each player is allowed a maximum of three calls per game (deal). Since each call adds two cards to a player's hand, you can check how many calls you have made by counting the cards in your hand. Calls that were not allowed by the player whose turn it was or which were unsuccessful because another player called first do not count towards the three.
A player who has laid down cards can no longer call.


The South African Kalooki Pagat Page literally features buying a card (and putting up an additional stake if you take the discard out of turn)

Buying cards
If you want a card that has been discarded, but it is not your turn to play next, you may be able to buy the card. If several people want the same discard, the player in turn always has prior right to it, and if this player does not want it, it goes to the first player in clockwise order after the player in turn who wishes to buy it. The player in turn can take the discard without payment, but if another player buys the discard the procedure is:

the player whose turn it was draws the top card of the stock;
the buyer adds 10 cents (R0.10) to the kitty;
the buyer takes the top discard and also draws the top card from the face down stock;
the buyer cannot meld or discard at this point, so will now have two extra cards;
the player whose turn it was continues their turn.

Each player can buy a maximum of four cards in each round, which would increase the size of their hands by eight cards. These extra cards can obviously be useful in forming combinations, but can also be expensive if you are caught with them when someone else goes out.

If you aren't playing for money though (which would make sense with this kind of score sheet, which seems to just track numerical scores), then putting up an additional stake to buy a card doesn't really make sense.
For scoring, maybe just use the basic scoring for Contract Rummy?

Face cards - 10 pts
Joker - 15 pts
Ace - 15 pts
T - 10 pts
2 through 9 - face value

This seems to be common to the family, I didn't see substantial variation in card values.

Excellent observations. We have been piecing it together with family members. We played this growing up in Connecticut, USA, so might be a New England variant of a rummy game. I’ve attached the scorecard.  All sets, no runs. Initially dealt 10 cards. Your ideas on buying the discard are spot on, only you also get two top cards from the deck. Scoring is Jokers -50, 2’s and aces -20, face cards -10, others -5. Only 2s are wild the first four hands. Then Jokers and aces and 2s. Low score wins. But here’s the catch. If a player ends up with an exact score of 710, they split the pot. Thanks.
